# How to remove a category from url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Now I have *urls* such as:

```
mysite.com/category/football
mysite.com/category/volleyball
mysite.com/category/hockey
```

And it corresponds to the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ category/index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But also I have other pages like: `mysite.com/feedback` or something...

How to remove `category` from url not affecting other pages?

If I'll do the rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Every other page will be a category, maybe it must be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(football|volleyball|hockey)$ category/index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But categories can be different. The admin can add new category or remove|change old.

**update**

I did an example in files:

**feedback/index.php**

```
   <h1>Feedback</h1>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ category.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**category.php**

```
// controller category

echo "This is a Category: <br />";

if (isset($_GET['category']) and !empty($_GET['category']))
{
    echo "<b>".$_GET['category']."</b>";
}
```

**index.php**

```
<a href="/football">Football</a>
<a href="/volleyball">Volleyball</a>
<a href="/hockey">Hockey</a>

<p>
    <a href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
</p>
```

So u can feel this trouble.

Comment: why not add a rule `RewriteRule ^feedback/([^/]*)$ feedback/index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @AviAtion: What is the `RewriteRule` associated with other URLs? Do you have only specific list of such URLs, or they also should be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly you want to support something *dynamic* (not necessarily *predefined*) in your URLs. If you know these categories upfront and they won't be conflicting with other URLs, you can add this rewrite rule.

But if this should be dynamic, rewrite rules are out of question. In such case you should handle the URLs in your app (or any other place having access to the database containing information about available categories).

On the other hand, if the list of categories is dynamic, but every other URL is predefined (eg. "`feedback`" probably is), just put rewrite rules responsible for these predefined URLs before the rewrite rule responsible for categories - they will take precendence.